# Android getting data from API so slow when using Mobile Data connection

Tags: android, laravel, digital-ocean, vps, loopj

based on my title.

Right now I am using vps from DigitalOcean to deploy the API (using laravel).

when I debug my apps, its really fast when getting data using WiFi. But, when I turn off the WiFi and turn on my data connection its really slow, almost take 10 sec to retrieve Json data, I don't know where is the problem, Mobile or Server.

I already upgrading the vps to 4GB, but its still not fixed the problem.

anyway I'm using AsyncHttpClient to retrieve data from API in android.

Comment: Have you tried using volley or retrofit

Comment: not yet @Rafsanjani

Comment: Don't upgrade the vps. The server should be fast regardless of the mode of connection. First make sure your mobile internet is stable enough then try implementing your logic using either retrofit or volley(I prefer retrofit) and compare the speeds once again